# Is it possible to run php code inside VBScript block in a .asp file?

Tags: php, vbscript

Is it possible to run some php code in a VBScript block in a .asp file?

Something like:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
Set str = <?php $s = "hello world"; echo $s; ?>
%>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work.

But classic ASP and VBScript is a combination that is similar to PHP.
See [classic ASP reference](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_introduction.asp).

The code in your question will look like

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
s = "hello world"
Response.Write(s)
%>
```

Comment: is it possible to have php code block and vb code block in the same .asp file though?

Comment: No, you have to stick with a single language, as there's only 1 interpreter handling the code in the file.